# How to make gcc compiler reserve registers when building intel-style inline assembly code?

Tags: debugging, gcc, assembly, xcode4, inline-assembly

I am building some intel-style inline assembly code using gcc compiler on Xcode 4.
Below lists part of the inline assembly code:

```
_asm
{   
    mov eax, esp
    sub esp, 116
    and esp, ~15
    mov [esp+112], eax       
}
```

Under ship mode, GCC compiles the above 4 lines asm code to:

```
mov    %esp,%eax
sub    $0x74,%esp
and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
mov    %eax,0x70(%esp)
```

which are exactly what I want.
However, under debug mode GCC will compiler that code to

```
mov    %esp,%eax
mov    %eax,%esp
mov    %esp,%eax
mov    %eax,-0x28(%ebp)
mov    %esp,%eax
mov    %eax,%esp
sub    $0x74,%esp
mov    %esp,%eax
mov    %eax,-0x24(%ebp)
mov    %esp,%eax
mov    %eax,%esp
**and    $0xfffffff0,%esp**         
**mov    %esp,%eax**        **//changing the value of “eax”**
mov    %eax,-0x24(%ebp)
mov    %esp,%ecx
mov    %ecx,%esp
**mov    %eax,0x70(%esp)**  **//store a “dirty” value to address 0x70(%esp), which is not we want**
```

One way to solve the above problem is to rewrite the inline asm code using AT&T style instructions and add the register to the clobbered list. But this way would be a very time-consuming work since the code to rewrite is so…o long.

Are there any other efficient ways to solve the problem? To make the gcc compiler know that register “eax” should be reserved?

Comment: The incline code uses register eax to store an improtant value, but GCC uses "eax" as an temporary register and "pollutes" register "eax". How to avoid this?

Comment: What do you mean preserved?  After the end of the inline-asm statement?  That makes no sense; once your asm statement is done the compiler owns the registers again.  If you want the function to return something you left in `eax`, you need to make that happen with a C variable.  The containing the asm block function could be inlined into another function...

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways:

1. The best way to solve it is using gcc assembly template
   capabilities. Then you can tell the compiler WHAT you're doing an
   the register allocator will not use your registers for anything
   else.
2. A quickhack would be to just use "asm volatile" instead of "asm" that way gcc will not reschedule
   any instructions inside that block. You'll still have to tell GCC
   that you're using the register so it's not going to store anything
   in there. You should also list "memory" in the clobber list, so gcc
   knows that it can't trust values it might have loaded before your
   code-block.

   asm volatile(
     "Code goes here"
     : : : "eax", "esp", "memory"
   );

Btw: Your code is doing some "bad things" like moving esp around, which might cause trouble down the line, unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: As I said, the code is very long and complicated, what I posted here is just a very small part of the original code. It would be very time-consuming to rewrite the whole code using the second way you proposed. Is there other way to declare that register eax has been reserved?

Comment: In fact, there are many other instructions after
    mov eax, esp
    sub esp, 116
    and esp, ~15
    mov [esp+112], eax

which are not convenient to be posted here.

Comment: You'll just have to add the `: : : "eax", "esp", "memory"` part to the end of your assembly code and declare the block as volatile. You also need to add all the register you're clobbering to the list. Then gcc will do the "right thing".

Comment: Yes, I get what you are suggesting. But the above code has been written using Intel-style instructions, where there are many macro definitions, memory access, etc. inside the asm{} block.

Comment: @behe: you could compile with `-masm=intel`, so you can use GNU `as`'s version of Intel syntax inside a GNU C Extended asm statement, with proper input and output constraints.  You'd probably only have to change a few instructions that dealt with getting data into / out of the asm block, not mass convert everything to AT&T syntax.

Answer (score -1):

An empty `asm` block after the intel-style block solves the problem, like this:

```
__asm volatile {   
    mov eax, esp
    sub esp, 116
    and esp, ~15
    mov [esp+112], eax       
};
__asm__ __volatile__ ("":::"eax", "memory");
```

However, if you don't restore `%esp`, it's going to wreak havoc.